# Find periods of time frequency in Pandas dataframe with multiple frequencies

Tags: python, pandas, frequency

I have multiple Pandas datetime-indexed dataframes, where the index frequency for some dataframes is constant throughout, but for others the frequency switches at some unknown point. For example, the frequency may switch from 5-minute to 1-minute, or from 15-minute to 1-hour.

How can I identify the different frequencies present in the index, and return the start and end times for each?

Here is an example dataframe. Note the switch from 5-minute frequency to 1-minute frequency at `1997-01-01 09:30:00` (magnitude of `var_1` happens to change here also, but this is arbitrary).

```
                        var_1
Datetime                       
1997-01-01 07:00:00     10.28
1997-01-01 07:05:00     11.00
1997-01-01 07:10:00     11.06
1997-01-01 07:15:00     11.06
1997-01-01 07:20:00     10.89
1997-01-01 07:25:00     11.39
1997-01-01 07:30:00     11.78
1997-01-01 07:35:00     11.83
1997-01-01 07:40:00     11.94
1997-01-01 07:45:00     12.06
1997-01-01 07:50:00     12.39
1997-01-01 07:55:00     12.61
1997-01-01 08:00:00     12.33
1997-01-01 08:05:00     12.28
1997-01-01 08:10:00     12.44
1997-01-01 08:15:00     12.50
1997-01-01 08:20:00     12.44
1997-01-01 08:25:00     12.11
1997-01-01 08:30:00     11.78
1997-01-01 08:35:00     11.61
1997-01-01 08:40:00     11.50
1997-01-01 08:45:00     11.56
1997-01-01 08:50:00     11.72
1997-01-01 08:55:00     11.67
1997-01-01 09:00:00     11.56
1997-01-01 09:05:00     11.56
1997-01-01 09:10:00     11.56
1997-01-01 09:15:00     11.11
1997-01-01 09:20:00     11.11
1997-01-01 09:25:00     11.33
1997-01-01 09:30:00      2.63
1997-01-01 09:31:00      2.62
1997-01-01 09:32:00      2.58
1997-01-01 09:33:00      2.62
1997-01-01 09:34:00      2.67
1997-01-01 09:35:00      2.68
1997-01-01 09:36:00      2.65
1997-01-01 09:37:00      2.57
1997-01-01 09:38:00      2.43
1997-01-01 09:39:00      2.31
1997-01-01 09:40:00      2.21
1997-01-01 09:41:00      2.13
1997-01-01 09:42:00      2.04
1997-01-01 09:43:00      1.94
1997-01-01 09:44:00      1.82
1997-01-01 09:45:00      1.75
1997-01-01 09:46:00      1.72
1997-01-01 09:47:00      1.71
1997-01-01 09:48:00      1.64
1997-01-01 09:49:00      1.59
1997-01-01 09:50:00      1.54
1997-01-01 09:51:00      1.47
1997-01-01 09:52:00      1.39
1997-01-01 09:53:00      1.31
1997-01-01 09:54:00      1.24
1997-01-01 09:55:00      1.20
1997-01-01 09:56:00      1.19
1997-01-01 09:57:00      1.18
1997-01-01 09:58:00      1.16
1997-01-01 09:59:00      1.13
```

Ideally, I would like to return something like:

```
freq1 = ['1997-01-01 07:00:00', '1997-01-01 09:30:00', '5T']
freq2 = ['1997-01-01 09:30:00', '1997-01-01 09:59:00', '1T']
```

Where the list items are [start time, end time, frequency].

My goal is take any dataframe with unknown frequency distribution, and return the time periods for each frequency that is present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option. Create a `Series` that increments when the frequency changes, and use that to form groups.

```
df = df.reset_index()
s = df.Datetime.diff().bfill().ne(df.Datetime.diff().shift(-1).ffill()).cumsum()

# Only so the name isn't <lambda>
def freq(x):
    return pd.infer_freq(x)

freqs = df.groupby(s).Datetime.agg([min, max, freq]).rename_axis(None, 0)
freqs['max'].update(freqs['min'].shift(-1))  # Fix the end times

                  min                 max freq
0 1997-01-01 07:00:00 1997-01-01 09:30:00   5T
1 1997-01-01 09:30:00 1997-01-01 09:59:00    T
```

Comment: for your function `freq`, you can use `pd.infer_freq(x)` to get it like '5T' :)

Comment: Wow, that one is new to me

Comment: I believe there's an of-by-one between your answer and what the OP asked for; the OP seems to want to have the time before the frequency changes to be both the end of that group and the beginning of the next.

Comment: Hmmm, that's quite a pesky problem. I'm guessing it will need to be fixed after the fact with this method since to my knowledge each row can only belong to one group.

Comment: The output will work fine either way (with or without the shared start/end timestamps).

Comment: @PJW Yeah let me know what you find. I have some doubts about how this will behave if the frequency changes rapidly from row to row For instance, `infer_freq` needs at least 3 dates per group, so you may need to exclude those small groups if they occur, or specify an alternative method to calculate the time frequency.

Comment: @ALollz Should be good. For most my test cases, certain frequencies persist for years.

Comment: Shouldn't we be passing something to `freq()`? I'm getting `ValueError: Need at least 3 dates to infer frequency`.

Comment: @PJW no, agg will look in the namespace for all functions, so it will find `freq` and pass the column as its argument. You're getting that error because one of the groups has less than 3 observations. Look at `df.groupby(s).size()` and you should see that there is at least one < 3.

Comment: if necessary, you can add a `try... except` clause to `freq`, perhaps either returning `None` when it can't calculate a frequency